# Django Azure AD Integration

Tags: django, azure, django-sessions

I'm currently integrating SSO  using Azure AD for a Django Project. I'm currently using the package: https://github.com/leibowitz/django-azure-ad-auth . I have followed the docs to setup the Azure AD Authentication . On entering the application url, it takes me to the microsoft login page and after entering the credentials it's redirected to the application. But on redirection to the application after the Azure Auth, the code checks in the session for 'nonce' & 'state' variables , which are strangely returned as None and hence the application redirects to the failure url.

```py
@never_cache
def auth(request):
    backend = AzureActiveDirectoryBackend()
    redirect_uri = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(complete))
    nonce = str(uuid.uuid4())
    request.session['nonce'] = nonce
    state = str(uuid.uuid4())
    request.session['state'] = state
    login_url = backend.login_url(
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
        nonce=nonce,
        state=state
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(login_url)


@never_cache
@csrf_exempt
def complete(request):
    backend = AzureActiveDirectoryBackend()
    method = 'GET' if backend.RESPONSE_MODE == 'fragment' else 'POST'
    original_state = request.session.get('state')
    state = getattr(request, method).get('state')
    if original_state == state:
        token = getattr(request, method).get('id_token')
        nonce = request.session.get('nonce')
        user = backend.authenticate(token=token, nonce=nonce)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(get_login_success_url(request))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('failure')
```

This is the code used for authentication.

Settings.py sample is given below:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'azure_ad_auth.backends.AzureActiveDirectoryBackend',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login_successful/'

AAD_TENANT_ID = 'd472b4f4-95c5-4eb3-8a9a-3615c837eada'
AAD_CLIENT_ID = '75e38b53-8174-4dc6-a8f6-bb7a913f1565'

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 86400 # sec
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'DSESSIONID'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Traceback

```py
TypeError at /TypeError at /project/azure/complete/
must be str, not NoneType
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://testdomain.com/project/azure/complete/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
must be str, not NoneType
Exception Location: /home/project/azure_auth/views.py in complete, line 57
Python Executable:  /home/project/app/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/home/project/app/project',
 '/home/project/app/venv/bin',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib64/python36.zip',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib64/python3.6',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 19 Nov 2019 05:21:10 +0000/azure/complete/
must be str, not NoneType
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://testdomain.com/project/azure/complete/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
must be str, not NoneType
Exception Location: /home/project/app/project/azure_auth/views.py in complete, line 57
Python Executable:  /home/project/app/venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/home/project/app/project',
 '/home/project/app/venv/bin',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib64/python36.zip',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib64/python3.6',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/project/app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 19 Nov 2019 05:21:10 +0000


/home/project/app/project/azure_auth/views.py in complete
            f.write("nonce -->"+nonce+"\n") …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
backend 
<azure_auth.backends.AzureActiveDirectoryBackend object at 0x7f5c688dce80>
data    
['82aff4f9-2cc0-4521-aea7-ad3281d20774\n',
 'ba821364-86c9-4233-881f-bdc772f7c488\n']
f   
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='t1.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
method  
'POST'
n   
'82aff4f9-2cc0-4521-aea7-ad3281d20774'
nonce   
None
original_state  
None
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/project/azure/complete/'>
state   
'fd93da6a-9009-4363-9640-9364df7f64df'
token   
'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyIsImtpZCI6IkJCOENlRlZxeWFHckdOdWVoSklpTDRkZmp6dyJ9.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.Rvc6xcPRZ01iebYtEyAWeyDnQEUVtqV1L1mapr658jLog-_yIASyEm3kMrkt6dIWWEO3dJSe3k05xOJlbnHqcjaR5LKAwOZzGR_oBmyIyB8-IvuEankNVpwYtcz8mY7kFr6AqQmIsx7xLLgv4grp-bSy4eRqjk36VeLX_LwMBuM_U6V70w0gXN1vvFCj0tjsv-VtTAmNgvdxS0ltzdD3rzZ87DoXbPWmoozLtO9WBRsJvMuvn-frBtYUYkIhs3I-eVAO9ZG2IWEuLQx6k7RBmzX6HgFi9SVpyEhNru7fmwO-qj5uRj9FQa45lCZluUV25o_AV1NQ94d5lnFyeMh7uw'
user    
None
```

I got the above error while trying to write the session variables to file (for debugging.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question! Could you include your code and the full error traceback?

Comment: Hi I have added the code from the azure auth package & sample settings. Actually the error is that the session values for nonce & state is None in the function complete

Comment: Can you include the full traceback, debugging with it is way easier

Comment: @Susreethaeks : how did u solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but the session won't be able to be retrieved (and with it the original state and nonce), and will fail the comparison if the cookie is not being sent by the browser.

The cookie is not sent by default in django 2.1+, since the default settings add `SameSite=Lax`

> The cookies used for django.contrib.sessions, django.contrib.messages,
>   and Django’s CSRF protection now set the SameSite flag to Lax by
>   default. Browsers that respect this flag won’t send these cookies on
>   cross-origin requests. If you rely on the old behavior, set the
>   SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE and/or CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE setting to None.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.1/#samesite-cookies

In theory this should still send the cookie ([from what I understand](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/)), but for some reason chrome doesn't seem to. There's something I clearly do not understand, so if anyone knows better please comment.

Anyway, changing the setting via `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` should work.

Comment: Thanks Gianni!!! I was struggling with this for days!!!