# Can't read session data from database

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have inherited a legacy Django application (currently on `2.2.24`), that I am trying to modernize step by step. One requirement is to move from MySQL to an Azure SQL database.

Unfortunately, I ran into an issue, where I just can't read back the session data from the database.

This is what my **settings.py** looks like. As you can see, `django.contrib.sessions` is set, as well as `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`. Also, I have explicitly set `SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'`, which should be the default.

```
# ...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    # ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
]
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
]
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql', # https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django
        'NAME': '<hiden>',
        'USER': '<hiden>',
        'PASSWORD': '<hiden>',
        'HOST': '<hiden>',
        'PORT': '1433,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
# ...
```

This is what the misbehaving **views.py** looks like, which is part of an Azure AD login procedure (`def auth(request)` => `sso/login` & `def complete(request)` => `sso/complete`)

After execution leaves `def auth(request)`, I can see a new entry in the table `dbo.django_session`. However, when execution enters `def complete(request)`, the session dictionary is empty.

```
@never_cache
def auth(request):
    request.session.flush()
    
    nonce = str(uuid.uuid4())
    request.session['nonce'] = nonce # store to session db

    state = str(uuid.uuid4())
    request.session['state'] = state # store to session db

    backend = AzureActiveDirectoryBackend()
    redirect_uri = AZURE_AD_REDIRECT_URI or request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(complete))
    login_url = backend.login_url(
        nonce=nonce,
        state=state,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri
    )

    if settings.DEBUG:
        print('login_url:', login_url)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(login_url)

@never_cache
@csrf_exempt
def complete(request):
    backend = AzureActiveDirectoryBackend()
    method = 'GET' if backend.RESPONSE_MODE == 'fragment' else 'POST' # form_post / fragment
    
    # EMPTY 
    keys = request.session.keys()
    items = request.session.items()

    # EMPTY AS WELL 
    original_state = request.session.get('state') # dictionary from SessionMiddleware

    resp_meta = getattr(request, method) # request.GET / request.POST
    state = resp_meta.get('state')

    if original_state != state:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>State is lost</h1>\n\nRefresh the page (F5).')

    if "error" in resp_meta:
        return HttpResponse('<h1>%s</h1> \n %s \n\n error_uri:<a>%s</a>' % (
            resp_meta['error'], resp_meta['error_description'], resp_meta['error_uri']))

    # ...
```

What is going on here? Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

**Update**

Other things I have tried in the meantime without success:

- Starting with a fresh database
- Recreating the `SECRET_KEY`
- Calling `request.session.modified = True`

**Update**

I just found out, that the `request.session.session_key` is empty when `def complete(request)` gets called!!

The user browses to `sso/login` (`def auth(request)`) and gets redirected to Microsoft, where he authenticates. After successful login the browser returns to `sso/complete` (`def complete(request)`).

Comment: Try setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to `False` if it is `True`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: Found it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912624/django-azure-ad-integration. Setting `CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` and `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE` made it work!!!